# Use Carbon Model on laravel blade the path error

Tags: laravel, assets, laravel-blade, php-carbon

when I use the carbon on my blade

```
localhost:8000/todo.blade.php
```

I use

```
 {{ Carbon::parse($chunk->time)->diffForHumans()}}
```

But when I use the cabon on my blade

```
localhost:8000/todo/todolist.blade.php
```

I must use

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($chunk->time)->diffForHumans()}}
```

why the url is different and how can I use the same code on the any location
just like

```
 {{ Carbon::parse($chunk->time)->diffForHumans()}}
```

Or can I use some code like asset()??

```
{{ asset(Carbon::parse($chunk->time)->diffForHumans())}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use `{{ Carbon::parse($chunk->time)->diffForHumans()}}` in any location you need register `Class Aliases`. Go to `config\app.php` and add to existing aliases new one:

```
'aliases' => [
//...other aliases
'Carbon' => \Carbon\Carbon::class
];
```

Now you can use `Carbon` instead of `\Carbon\Carbon` everywhere.